# php curl post with originators ip

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I  have a form where clients leave their email to be added to a mailing list and also get access to the site.

I make a post of form data to a php script that add the email to a mysql table together with a generated password. The password is then emailed to the client.

I would like to re-post the data to an auto responder, Aweber or similar, but want to preserve the IP address I received the client signup from. Like if they signed up on Aweber's form directly.

Is that possible to do with for example CURL or will all re-posts have my servers IP?

Comment: I could put the Aweber form on the signup page, and make a Ajax post to my php script and send the original form on callback.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to spoof the IP address ***in the headers***:

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$headers = array(
    "REMOTE_ADDR: " . $ipAddress,
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: " . $ipAddress
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Results may vary.

Unfortunately, with cURL, you can't really "spoof" an IP address. If you need to spoof an IP address, you'll need to look into using sockets.